# SQL result array, from PDO query, has duplicated values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a mysql table that has the following fields

```
STUDENTID  |  FIRSTNAME |  SURNAME  |  DOB   |  SCHOOLID
```

A form is used for a user to search for a student and output all those with matching first and surnames

The following SQL statement returns the PDO fine

```php
$sqlstmnt2 = 'SELECT * FROM students WHERE firstName = :fname AND surname = :sname AND schoolID = :schoolID';

// prepare PDOstatement as $query ...
// ...

$query->execute();
$_SESSION['foundPupils'] = $query->fetchAll();
```

However, when I pass this through to another PHP page in a session variable, I'm confused as to how to access each field individually. I have the following code

```php
foreach($_SESSION['foundPupils'][0] as $found){
    echo($found);
}
```

This outputs the found data but the issue is that it outputs it twice, and it's just a long string of data which can't be formatted nicely. My questions are:

Why does each result output twice?
How do I access the individual fields within this array (kind of like foundPupils[0]['firstName'] for example?

Comment: You have not included the relevant pieces of your code. Where and how do you set `$_SESSION`? Depending on your fetch mode the default will return an mixed array with numeric and indexed keys both containing the corrosponding column values.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `var_export($_SESSION['foundPupils'][0])`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, both the method [PDOStatement::fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) and [PDOStatement::fetchAll](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) accepts a `$fetch_style` parameter. If not set, the default value is `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`. That means the fetched array will both reference the fields by position (e.g. 0, 1, 2) and by column name (e.g. `"firstName"`, `"surname"`).

So by default, your fetched results would be something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => apple
            [0] => apple
            [colour] => red
            [1] => red
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => pear
            [0] => pear
            [colour] => green
            [1] => green
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => watermelon
            [0] => watermelon
            [colour] => pink
            [1] => pink
        )

)
```

To fix this, you need to call your fetch function (I suppose it is [PDOStatement::fetchAll](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)) with `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN` as the fetch style:

```php
$query->execute();
$_SESSION['foundPupils'] = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

Answer (score -1):

Query results are returned and stored in a result object. Therefore, you have to iterate through the result either using xxxx_fetch_array or xxxx_fetch_row. for example

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM table_name';
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['COLUMN_NAME'].'<br />';
}
```